# How to enable logging everyting in Facebook iOS SDK for debugging purposes?

Tags: debugging, logging, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to debug my iOS app that integrates with Facebook iOS SDK 4.1.  I would like to see a verbose log of Facebook's code.  Is there a way to do that?  Right now I don't see any log from Facebook.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

As stated in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/constants/FBSDKSettings/), you can enable debug logs by invoking the following method:

```
[FBSDKSettings enableLoggingBehavior:FBSDKLoggingBehaviorAppEvents];
```

Swift 5:

```
Settings.enableLoggingBehavior(.appEvents)
```

Comment: Swift version for whoever may be interested ([as per documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/appevents#testing)):
`SDKSettings.enableLoggingBehavior(.appEvents)`

Comment: As of Oct 2019 - It;s now `Settings.enableLoggingBehavior(.appEvents)`

Comment: `Settings.shared.enableLoggingBehavior(.appEvents)`

Answer (score 0):

Enable debug logs to verify client-side app event usage using the following code. The debug logs contain detailed requests and responses formatted in JSON.

If you are using Swift language then

```
SDKSettings.enableLoggingBehavior(.AppEvents)
```

If you are working in Objective-C then you can use this below method to enable debug.

```
[FBSDKSettings enableLoggingBehavior:FBSDKLoggingBehaviorAppEvents];
```

**This is only for debugging purpose. Please make sure to disable debug logs before deploying app in production.**